# CSS3 image rotate

Tags: image, css

I want to *rotate* an image, but I can't find how to do it the way I need to, the picture below will give a better example. I know it's a YouTube picture but its the closest thing i could find to what I'm talking about!

An example of what I *don't* need is something like:

```css
-webkit-transform: rotate(-29deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-29deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-29deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(-29deg);
        transform: rotate(-29deg);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

It's more like image depth. Is it possible and if so how would I get the effect?

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydC7k.png)

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer if one of these responses helped you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

Perspective to the left:

```
-webkit-transform: perspective( 300px ) rotateY( 45deg );
-moz-transform: perspective( 300px ) rotateY( 45deg );
-ms-transform: perspective( 300px ) rotateY( 45deg );
-o-transform: perspective( 300px ) rotateY( 45deg );
transform: perspective( 300px ) rotateY( 45deg );
```

Perspective to the right:

```
-webkit-transform: perspective( 300px ) rotateY( -45deg );
-moz-transform: perspective( 300px ) rotateY( -45deg );
-ms-transform: perspective( 300px ) rotateY( -45deg );
-o-transform: perspective( 300px ) rotateY( -45deg );
transform: perspective( 300px ) rotateY( -45deg );
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4T6PV/3/)**

The magic is happening thanks to `perspective` and `rotate`, which you can read more about for example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective.

Comment: @user3547811 simple, just something like this: `<img src="image.jpg" alt id="left">`

Comment: it wont work, i uploaded my website files HERE http://www.filedropper.com/website_2   and here is a virus scanner https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/d85b7bc6c70bf5ca2640ea6b909fc3f0bd6966f7c08fb274b3751a1afa0e220e/analysis/1399481145/

Comment: sorry it took me so long to accept it, i was messing around with the code to get it perfect! thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to modify the 'perspective' of your images.

If you wanted to update the look of an image similar to one of the images in your example, you are going to want to do a mixture of `rotateY()` and `perspective`.

```
<img class="kitten" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/>

.kitten {
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 1000px ) rotateY( 45deg );
}
```

Check out this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/stat30fbliss/y2j4x/2/

Also worth checking out this CSS Tricks Article:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

As for modifying the perspective of the image based on scrolling or something along those lines, you will need some javascript computations that will produce the `perspective` and `rotateY` values.

Comment: Works good! Just curious: why is `position:relative` needed here?

Comment: @DanielLisik Great question, it's not!  Removed from the snippet and example :)

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use the `perspective` CSS3 transform property. The [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) for perspective give a good definition of how this property is to be used

> ***Perspective:***
>   The perspective CSS property determines the distance between the z=0 plane and the user in order to give to the 3D-positioned element some perspective. Each 3D element with z>0 becomes larger; each 3D-element with z<0 becomes smaller. The strength of the effect is determined by the value of this property.

Basically, the smaller the value of perspective (i.e. the closer the viewer is perceived to be from the DOM element), the greater the effect of the transformations (e.g. `rotateX`)

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fWdB3/)** showing a few 3D transforms in action. You should also check out this great article which demonstrates several different transformations you can do using CSS3 3D transforms: **[An Introduction to CSS 3-D Transforms](http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/)**

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="rotate-left"></div>
<div class="rotate-up"></div>
<div class="rotate-right"></div>
```

You want to give your element the following properties:

```
.rotate-left {
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateY( 35deg );
    -moz-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateY( 35deg );
    -ms-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateY( 35deg );
    -o-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateY( 35deg );
    transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateY( 35deg );
}

.rotate-right {
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateY( -35deg );
    -moz-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateY( -35deg );
    -ms-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateY( -35deg );
    -o-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateY( -35deg );
    transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateY( -35deg );
}

.rotate-up {
    -webkit-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateX( 35deg );
    -moz-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateX( 35deg );
    -ms-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateX( 35deg );
    -o-transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateX( 35deg );
    transform: perspective( 500px ) rotateX( 35deg );
}
```